# Appcelerator Titanium Module - Verification issue, unlicensed module(s)

Tags: module, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I had found a module in the appcelerator marketplace to allow for the rotate gesture called gesture recogniser but unfortunately it's now been removed when i went to purchase but it looks like the developer has also released the module as a 'skeleton' version on github here:

https://github.com/atsusy/Gesture-Recognizer

Now i followed the instructions on the readme file and built the project which created the module for me, when putting this into an app though i get the following error message and red screen:

```
Verification issue
Unlicensed module(s) detected.
You must be a subscriber to use one or more of the modules included with this project
```

Is there something i have missed to get this and how to i go about resolving the issue? Sorry i have no clue when it comes to github and modules so apologies if i am trying to use this in my app when i shouldn't but if anyone can help explain how and if i am allowed to get this working?

p.s the original link for the marketplace link that is now not found is: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/http-status/?1894758329

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow steps as follows:

1. Open Terminal and run “uuidgen”
2. Copy the code you see on the terminal
3. Open tiapp.xml, replace what’s in the “guid” tag with the the code you copied.
4. In Titanium Studio, do Project –> Clean
5. Run

Concept is to change GUID of module which is mentioned in manifest.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source code, just go the the manifest file, change the guid in the manifest to a new one, and build the module again. Probably better to increase the version and include it in your project again. Clean and build and it will work.

I guess the Titanium studio checks if you have licence for the modules you use. In case a module is on the marketplace with the same guid and you have no licence for that, it triggers it as unlicensed module.